# Taylor polynomial explanation

Tags: taylor-expansion

> Let $$f(x) = \frac1{1+x^2}$$. What can you say about approximating $f(x)$ over $[−5, 5]$ by Taylor polynomials about $x = 0$?

I don't really understand what this question is asking. How would Taylor polynomials be used here?

Comment: Not sure what it's asking either. Perhaps they just mean for you to notice that you can just use "long division" to get $f(x)=1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\cdots$.

Comment: One point is that (as you can check), the Taylor expansion (as @ElliotG observes) is obtainable as a geometric series... and then it is easy to see that the _infinite_ Taylor series only converges in $(-1,+1)$. But one can still contemplate the Taylor-series-with-error-term...

Comment: @ElliotG: Do you mean division by increasing powers?

Comment: $\displaystyle P(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k.~$
$f(x) = (1 + x^2)^{(-1)}.~$
$f^{(1)}(x) = (-1)(1 + x^2)^{(-2)}(2x)~.$ The way that I read this, Elliot G.'s comment, though natural, involves a geometric series rather than the Taylor series.  As I understand it, (and I could be mistaken) for the interval of $[-5, 5]$ you would have $\int_{-5}^5 P(x)dx.$  I think the "What can you say..." question is asking you to **integrate the error term** rather than $P(x)$.  **However, I am just guessing.**  Strikes me as an *offbeat* but interesting question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Taylor series around 0 converges only for $\lvert x \rvert < 1$, so this just won't work.